# What is the best approach for coding in a slow compilation environment?

Tags: c++, tdd, build-process

I used to be coding in C# in a TDD style - write/or change a small chunk of code, re-compile in 10 seconds the whole solution, re-run the tests and again. Easy...

That development methodology worked very well for me for a few years, until a last year when I had to go back to C++ coding and it really feels that my productivity has dramatically decreased since. The C++ as a language is not a problem - I had  quite a lot of C++ dev experience... but in the past.

My productivity is still OK for a small projects, but it gets worse when with the increase of the project size and once compilation time hits 10+ minutes it gets really bad. And if I find the error I have to start compilation again, etc. That is just purely frustrating.

Thus I concluded that in a small chunks (as before) is not acceptable - any recommendations how can I get myself into the old gone habit of coding for an hour or so, when reviewing the code manually (without relying on a fast C# compiler), and only recompiling/re-running unit tests once in a couple of hours.

With a C# and TDD it was very easy to write a code in a evolutionary way - after a dozen of iterations whatever crap I started with was ending up in a good code, but it just does not work for me anymore (in a slow compilation environment).

Would really appreciate your inputs and recos.

p.s. not sure how to tag the question - anyone is welcome to re-tag the question appropriately.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you use Makefile to compile only the files that changes or do you recompile everything from scratch even for compilation units that have not changed?

Comment: 10 minutes? Count yourself lucky you don't have to punch cards each time around!

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? 10 Minutes is really long, even for C++ standards.

Comment: what environment are you using (OS, IDE, etc.)? Compiling 1-hour-worth of work should not take long, unless something is wrong with your environment or program structure. Also, Eclipse for instance detects many syntax errors while editing

Comment: 10 minutes is not long - The app I work on takes a full hour for a clean build. Luckily an incremental build is only around 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that recompiling and testing sort of pulls me out of the "zone", so in order to have the benefits of TDD, I commit fairly often into a git repository, and run a background process that checks out any new commit, runs the full test suite and annotates the commit object in git with the result. When I get around to it (usually in the evening), I then go back to the test results, fix any issues and "rewrite history", then re-run the tests on the new history. This way I don't have to interrupt my work even for the short times it takes to recompile (most of) my projects.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you can't use TDD with C++.  I used CppUnit back in 2001, so I assume it's still in place.

You don't say what IDE or build tool you're using, so I can't comment on how those affect your pace.  But small, incremental compiles and running unit tests are both still possible.

Perhaps looking into Cruise Control, Team City, or another hands-off build and test process would be your cup of tea.  You can just check in as fast as you can and let the automated build happen on another server.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can avoid the long compile. Aside from improving the quality of your build files/process, you may be able to pick just a small thing to build. If the file you're working on is a .cpp file, just compile that one TU and unit-test it in isolation from the rest of the project. If it's a header (perhaps containing inline functions and templates), do the same with a small number of TUs that between them reference most of the functionality (if no such set of TUs exists, write unit tests for the header file and use those). This lets you quickly detect obvious stupid errors (like typos) that don't compile, and runs the subset of tests you *believe* to be relevant to the changes you're making. Once you have something that might vaguely work, do a proper build/test of the project to ensure you haven't broken anything you didn't realise was relevant.

Where a long compile/test cycle is unavoidable, I work on two things at once. For this to be efficient, one of them needs to be simple enough that it can just be dropped when the main task is ready to be resumed, and picked up again immediately when the main task's compile/test cycle is finished. This takes a bit of planning. And of course the secondary task has its own build/test cycle, so sometimes you want to work in separate checked-out copies of the source so that errors in one don't block the other.

The secondary task could for example be, "speed up the partial compilation time of the main task by reducing inter-component dependencies". Even so you may have hit a hard limit once it's taking 10 minutes just to link your program's executable, since splitting the thing into multiple dlls just as a development hack probably isn't a good idea. The key thing to avoid is for the secondary task to be, "hit SO", or [this](http://xkcd.com/303/).

Comment: +1 for the comics, -1 for "don't SO" :) These are blessed interludes to learn something new

Comment: @davka: Well I'm here now (on lunch rather than compiling time in this instance), so of course I'm not anti-SO. But it's for education, it doesn't improve your productivity *today*, and refreshing it every time you hit compile won't get you to your deadlines any faster. If you don't have any deadlines then the secondary task could be "read a book", "work on the design of the next project", or "do some sit-ups", but I'm assuming the questioner wants to focus his time effectively on his current programming project :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since a simple change triggers a 10 minutes recompilation, that means you have a bad build system. Your build should recompile only changed files and files depending on the changed files.

Other then that, there are other techniques to speed up the build time (For example, try to remove unneeded includes. Then instead of including a header, use forward declaration. etc ), but the speed up of these things is not that important as what is recompiled on a change.